# Why default properties in external JS file were not overwritten with user defined properties in object?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I have an HTML and JS file. Should the user want to overwrite the default settings that are declared in the external JS file all they have to do is include the following as an inline script:

```
<script>
    userControls = { 
        transition : 'fade',
        nextText : 'Next'
    }
</script>
```

The problem I am facing is that my external script is not picking up the user settings and is setting everything as default.

```js
var defControls = {
        transition : 'default',
        nextText : 'Next &raquo;'
    };
    var userControls = {};    
    
    // CHECKS FOR userControls
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userControls).length > 0) {
        var controls = Object.assign({}, defControls, userControls);
    } else {
        controls = defControls;
    }

    console.log(userControls);
    console.log(controls);
    console.log(defControls);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- EXTERNAL SCRIPT THAT ACCEPTS USER'S NEW SETTINGS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- SENDS THE NEW PARAMETERS TO script.js -->
<script>
userControls = { 
 transition : 'fade',
 nextText : 'Next'
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var userControls = {};` overwrites them with an empty object.

Comment: Also you need to place the code with the customisation either above the external script, so that its values can be taken into account when it is executed, or you need to have the external script define a function that the customisation script can call (with arguments preferably) afterwards.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you for your feedback. I'm trying to implement a FancyBox-like solution where it's minimal inline code that gets passed/called. Is there another option that wouldn't require me moving the inline code or creating a new function and then calling it in the HTML?

Comment: Not really - using a function is the way to go.

Comment: @Bharata, thank you for your solution. I am trying to implement your solution into my script but it is only half working. I'm trying to figure out what I can before I respond. Thank you for your patience. I promise I will get back and mark this as the answer once it is completely working.

Comment: @Peter, please rollback your question to version #2 because nobody will understand our answers and everyone have to understand your question. The list of versions you can find **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52229962/revisions)**. Click on "rollback" by version #2 please.

Comment: @Bharata, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four and half mistakes in your code:

1. You have to write inline script with code: `var userControls = {transition: 'fade', nextText: 'Next'};` before external JS file. And do not forget `;` on the end (it is the half mistake).
2. The line `var userControls = {};` **in external JS file** has overwrited the settings in `userControls` **in inline script**. I think you wanted to write instead `var controls = {};`.
3. The `var controls = {};` you have to write before `if...else` statement.
4. You write `console.log(userControls);` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(userControls));` Your code writes only `[object Object]` in developer console from IE. But in Chrome it is okey.

**Solution with corrected code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<!-- 
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 -->
<!-- SENDS THE NEW PARAMETERS TO script.js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var userControls =
{ 
    transition : 'fade',
    nextText : 'Next'
};
</script>

<!-- EXTERNAL SCRIPT THAT ACCEPTS USER'S NEW SETTINGS
 src="script.js" -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var defControls =
{
    transition : 'default',
    nextText : 'Next &raquo;'
};
//THIS WAS THE MISTAKE: var userControls = {}; this line has overwrited the settings

var controls = {};

// CHECKS FOR userControls
if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userControls).length > 0)
{
    controls = Object.assign({}, defControls, userControls);
}
else
{
    controls = defControls;
}

console.log('userControls =\n' + JSON.stringify(userControls, null, '\t'));
console.log('controls =\n' + JSON.stringify(controls, null, '\t'));
console.log('defControls =\n' + JSON.stringify(defControls, null, '\t'));
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because that you inserted the user choice after your js file loads. It goes through the following control first

`if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(userControls).length > 0)`

so this will always evaluate to `false`. That's why you keep getting default values. You should either insert the user choice script first or some async functionality in the js file.

Comment: thank you for your response. I see what you are getting at but unfortunately that did not resolve the issue. Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: I just tried my solution with a few additional tweaks and it worked actually. 

First, carry your second script tag where the user picks the settings on the top and define `userControls` there with the var keyword

and remove the following line from script.js, so it won't reset our variables

`var userControls = {}`

after these changes, everything should be fine.